# How can I fix this XSL snippet to only display information if data is being passed?

Tags: if-statement, xslt, xml-parsing

I have the following snippet of XSL that is pulling in a link from data in a component.

```
<div class="announcements__cta">
<a href="{$href1}" class="cta cta--link"><xsl:value-of select="$label1"/></a></div>
```

Is there a way to write and if/else to exclude this snippet of code from displaying if there is no URL?

I am extremely new to XSL, so I have not tried anything as I'm not sure where to start. I have access to edit the XML in which the data is being parsed, and I've set the link to be optional; however, it is still coming across when being executed.

Comment: Please post a [mcve], not snippets of code taken out of context.

Comment: I apologize for posting the code with no context. that was not my intention.

Comment: Is your question answered?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, there are 2 methods of writing to the output only if some node exists:

1. Use a template matching the node. If the node doesn't exist, the
   template will not be instantiated;
2. Use a construct of:

   ```
   <xsl:if test="some-node">
      <some-output/>
   </xsl:if>
   ```